# React : call async method from same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call **removeCouponCode** method which exist in same file but execution says its not defined i am not sure what is missing here.
any thoughts ?
Below is the file which i am editing & trying to make changes.
not sure what is missing.

please have a look at let me know what is missing

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import SessionContext from 'react-storefront/session/SessionContext';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import fetch from 'react-storefront/fetch';
import get from 'lodash/get';
import { EventTracking, AnalyticsErrors } from '../analytics/Events';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import constants from '../constants/configs';
import errorHandler from '../constants/apiHelpers/errorHandler';
import Helper from '../constants/helper';
import configs from '../constants/configs';
const { session, actions } = useContext(SessionContext);
const initialState = {
  signedIn: false,
  cart: {
    items: [],
    shipping_methods: [],
    shippingCountry: null,
    shippingMethodCode: null,
    freeShipingMethod: null,
    freeShippingSelected: false
  },
  customer: {
    store_credit: {},
    wishlist: { items_count: 0, items: [] },
    offline: true
  },
  errMsg: ''
};
const initialStatusState = {
  cartLoadingStatus: false,
  setShippingMethodStatus: false
};

    async redemptionCode({ couponCode, ...otherParams }) {
          let tempSession = { ...session };
          const response = await fetch('/api/cart/redemptionCode', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ couponCode, ...otherParams })
          });

          const result = await response.json();

          if (response.ok) {
            if(get(result, 'cart.prices.discounts', {}) === null){
              removeCouponCode(...otherParams); //says undefined removeCouponCode here
            }
            
          }
        },
        async removeCouponCode({ ...otherParams }) {
          let tempSession = { ...session };
          const response = await fetch('/api/cart/removeCouponCode', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ ...otherParams })
          });
        },
```

Comment: It says "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: removeCouponCode is not defined"

Comment: Let me know if question not clear

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t reference your function and reference your function and try or you can either modify your code as follows by declaring it as a function,

```
async function removeCouponCode({ ...otherParams }) {
    let tempSession = { ...session };
    const response = await fetch('/api/cart/removeCouponCode', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ ...otherParams })
    });
}

async function redemptionCode({ couponCode, ...otherParams }) {
    let tempSession = { ...session };
    const response = await fetch('/api/cart/redemptionCode', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ couponCode, ...otherParams })
    });

    const result = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
        if(get(result, 'cart.prices.discounts', {}) === null){
            await removeCouponCode(...otherParams);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "("

async function removeCouponCode({ ...otherParams }) {

Comment: Are you using typescript ?

Comment: Its based on react

Comment: No, i am asking it is react js or react ts

Comment: i am not sure how to check it ?

Comment: Its using the development build of React. 

Open the developer tools, and "Components" and "Profiler" tabs will appear to the right.

Comment: So its reactJS page

Comment: redemptionCode also declare the same as removeCouponCode and define removeCouponCode before calling it inside if(response.ok)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234843/discussion-between-amesh-jayaweera-and-devhs).

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare them as `function`. So you define them either this way

```
async function redemptionCode({ couponCode, ...otherParams }) {
          let tempSession = { ...session };
          const response = await fetch('/api/cart/redemptionCode', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ couponCode, ...otherParams })
          });

          const result = await response.json();

          if (response.ok) {
            if(get(result, 'cart.prices.discounts', {}) === null){
              removeCouponCode(...otherParams); //says undefined removeCouponCode here
            }
            
          }
        },
        async function removeCouponCode({ ...otherParams }) {
          let tempSession = { ...session };
          const response = await fetch('/api/cart/removeCouponCode', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ ...otherParams })
          });
        },
```

Or this way

```
const redemptionCode = async ({ couponCode, ...otherParams }) => {
          let tempSession = { ...session };
          const response = await fetch('/api/cart/redemptionCode', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ couponCode, ...otherParams })
          });

          const result = await response.json();

          if (response.ok) {
            if(get(result, 'cart.prices.discounts', {}) === null){
              removeCouponCode(...otherParams); //says undefined removeCouponCode here
            }
            
          }
        },
        const removeCouponCode = async ({ ...otherParams }) => {
          let tempSession = { ...session };
          const response = await fetch('/api/cart/removeCouponCode', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ ...otherParams })
          });
        },
```

Both should work!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you define this function after calling it. I think you should first define it and then call it..and you can use the arrow function.